# How to change VisualState of UserControl used as ItemTemplate in ListView

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I've a *UserControl* with some *VisualStates* defined:

```xml
<UserControl>
  <Grid Height="50" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
            <VisualState x:Name="Unselected"/>
            <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
            <!-- more code -->
```

and I use it as an *ItemTemplate* of my *ListView*. When item from *ListView* is selected, I also want to change the *VisualState* of the *DataTemplate*. For now I've such a method:

```cs
private void list_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
  ListView listView = sender as ListView;
  foreach (var item in e.AddedItems)
    VisualStateManager.GoToState((listView.ContainerFromItem(item) as ListViewItem).ContentTemplateRoot as myControl, "Selected", false);
 }
```

It seems to work, but in some cases `(listView.ContainerFromItem(item) as ListViewItem` is *null* and therefore exception is thrown.

Is there any other/better way to change the *VisualState* of used *DataTemplate*?

Comment: So you want the visualstate set by the listview item to also be inherited automatically by the VSM in your UserControl to reflect it? Just to make sure I understand.

Comment: @ChrisW. Yes, that's right. For example I've a *TextBlock* in my *UserControl* and visual state manager changes it's foreground color. Once the list item is selected I want it to trigger.

Comment: And you can't say in which cases it does not work? If you find that out, you'll most likely be able to fix it. I could check it out if you provide some sample solution with it. Also, I'd use a `(cast)` instead of `as`.

Comment: @yasen As I observed the problem is (not always) when I not select item by touching the screen, but when I select item from code - for example by adding them to *SelectedItems* or setting *IsSelected*. I'll try to build a sample tomorrow and give you a sign.

Comment: Do you need virtualization for your `ListView`? Does it need to handle a lot of data?

Comment: @yasen It turned out that the problem was when the items were not rendered completely and added from code - take a look at JustinXL's answer. Thank you for for finding time to take a look at the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that the item container (i.e. `ListViewItem`) is `null` is because the `ListView`'s default panel `ItemsStackPanel` is a **pixel-based UI virtualization** panel which only renders items when they are *in or close to the current viewport*.

Since you set up the selected items in code, those items might not be rendered, their containers will return as `null`.

One simple fix would be to replace the `ItemsStackPanel` with a normal `StackPanel`, however doing this will break the built-in virtualization.

Here's another solution without modifying the panel.

First your existing code is still needed, you just need to do a null check, if the item container is null, simply do nothing.

Then, you need to subscribe to the `ListView`'s `ContainerContentChanging` event. This fires when the item container gets loaded. So basically, you check if the item that's loaded here is one of the selected items. If it is, then change its visual state. Something like this -

```
private void MyListView_ContainerContentChanging(ListViewBase sender, ContainerContentChangingEventArgs args)
{
    if (this.MyListView.SelectedItems.Contains(args.Item))
    {
        // get the container
        var container = (ListViewItem)args.ItemContainer; 

        // do your visual state change here, when the container was previously null
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like nice bunch of information, which will explain everything. I'll try little later and get back with results.

Comment: That was definitely the problem, now everything works just fine. Thank you for help.